# Changing with what is effectively a setter in one function resets back to its old state in another function

Tags: c++, sfml

```
#include "Healthbar.h"

Healthbar::Healthbar(const sf::Vector2f& size, const sf::Vector2f& position) 
: m_borderRect(size), m_bar(size)
{
    m_borderRect.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Red);
    m_borderRect.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    m_borderRect.setOutlineThickness(5);
    m_borderRect.setPosition(position);
    m_bar.setPosition(position); 
    m_bar.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green); 
}

void Healthbar::draw(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    window.draw(m_borderRect);
    window.draw(m_bar);
}

void Healthbar::damage(int num)
{
    m_bar.setSize(sf::Vector2f(m_bar.getSize().x - 100/num, m_bar.getSize().y));
}

int Healthbar::getBarSizeX() const
{
    return m_bar.getSize().x;
}
```

In spaceship class that contains a health bar:

```
Healthbar Spaceship::getHealth()
{
    return m_health;
}

int Spaceship::getSizeX() const
{
    return m_health.getBarSizeX();
}
```

Collision manager that interacts with enemyfleet projectiles and ship:

```
void CollisionManager::shipProjectileCollision(EnemyFleet& fleet, Spaceship& ship)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < fleet.getProjSize(); j++) {
        if (ship.checkCollision(fleet.getProjectile(j))) {
            ship.getHealth().damage(3);
        }
    }
}
```

In source file:

```
Spaceship ship; 
std::cout << ship.getHealth().getBarSizeX() << std::endl; // = 100
ship.getHealth().damage(3);
std::cout << ship.getHealth().getBarSizeX() << std::endl; //should be 66.67
```

I'm making space invaders. I'm trying to reduce the size of the health bar when the space ship collides with projectile by ~33.33 but it's not working. This seems similar to a getter and setter to me in traditional functions so I'm not sure what's going on here...

At the end of the "damage" function i put a breakpoint and it has the right size but then in the main function it goes to draw after i change the size and in the draw its always 100 for x in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
Healthbar Spaceship::getHealth()
```

You return a *value* from getHealth() so it is always a new instance, which is a copy of the original, which is likely initialized to have 100 as size. You could return a reference instead, e.g. `Healthbar& getHealth();`